# Writing JPA 2 metamodel classes by hand

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I want to write by hand a metamodel class for one of my entity classes.
Is it possible / simple to write the metamodel class by hand (only 3 singular fields)?
I know there're tools to generate it but for a simple test I'm having I prefer to write it by hand.
An Example for the following class will be appreciated:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private Integer val;
  public Integer getVal()...
  public void setVal(Integer val):...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple entity also metamodel is quite minimal:

```
package same.as.myentity;

import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@StaticMetamodel(MyEntity.class)
public class MyEntity_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyEntity, Integer> val;
}
```

Good documentation is offered by [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/metamodel.html). It is directly taken from the JPA 2.0 specification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I've tried but at run time I've got a null exception when using the val which is null. Any idea? Doesn't the variable should be initialized?